# JSON parse eror from query SELECT Mongoose in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have data from schema "notification" in Mongoose  like this :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c141ef2a7c50a773661772d"),
"title" : "MY POny",
"message" : "message POny",
"token" : "dHvoi4DQAMw:APA91bFGwBjDRCaOFaodRlgrVLKPLsXRlCymce5an_POCC5WlluOCbCbHWmXr2BvPqifdirxcSOwGJky-BBSyvDqj0ojwSrqDKrBHB0KwyNcZm2l-YHBpVkBlIOwfoiQkZsXZlFOxVj6",
"os" : "ANDROID",
"dateCreated" : ISODate("2018-12-14T14:21:51.834Z"),
"dateUpdated" : ISODate("2018-12-14T14:21:51.834Z"),
"deleted" : false,
"payload" : {
    "type" : "PROMO",
    "data" : {
        "message" : "blabalbla…",
        "url" : "https://www.pony.com/pony.png",
        "datetime" : "2018-02-06 17:00"
    }
},
"mobile" : "123456789101",
"id" : 171,
"__v" : 0,
"response" : {
    "multicast_id" : 4.83405561199415e+18,
    "success" : 1,
    "failure" : 0,
    "canonical_ids" : 0,
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "message_id" : "0:1544822514686455%29669a5329669a53"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

i have query like this

```
let getListNotif = await NOTIF.find({mobile : mobile, 'payload.type' : {$ne : 'TRANSACTION'}}).sort({'dateCreated': -1}).limit(limit)
```

i want to output like this :

```
let notifShow ={
        mobile : getListNotif.mobile,
        payload : getListNotif.payload
    }
```

why error json parse in node js when i want send like this :

```
res.status(200).json(notifShow)
```

Comment: Interesting. Nothing in the code you posted should cause that kind of error. Did you try console.log-ging notifShow?

Comment: Also, if mobile and payload are the only two fields you want from that query, you can use query projections to limit the amount of data being pulled from the DB. Give the string 'mobile payload' as the second argument to NOTIF.find

Answer (score 0):

fix done

```
try {
    let getListNotif = await NOTIF.find({'token' : token, 'payload.type' : {$ne : 'TRANSACTION'}}).sort({'dateCreated': -1}).limit(limit)
    let array = []
    let notifShow = {}
    for(let i = 0; i < getListNotif.length; i++){
        notifShow = {
            mobile : getListNotif[i].mobile,
            payload : getListNotif[i].payload
        }
        array.push(notifShow)
    }
    res.status(200).json(array)
} catch (error) {
    logger.error(error.message)
    res.status(422).json(Object.assign({message: error.message}, params))
}
```